# Bounds of the product of two variables

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose we have $$a<X<b$$ $$c < Y < d$$ $$ a, b, c, d \in R$$

Is this statement correct?
$$min(ac, ad, bc, bd) < X*Y<max(ac, ad, bc, bd)$$

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes it's correct. This is basic algebra.